# Поиск несуществующего значения SQlite

Tags: java, sqlite

Пишу приложение на java.

Что будет, если искать в БД SQlite несуществующее значение?
Он ответит null'ом?

И, если да, как мне написать if?

Правильно ли приравнивать `"null"` к полученной из таблицы строке с помощью `equals()`?

Comment: От запроса зависит `select xxx from table where a=1` не вернет ни одной строки, если строк с a=1 не найдет в базе. И следовательно надо проверять количество выбранных строк. А `select max(xxx) from table where a=1` всегда возвращает одну строку и если записей не было, либо поле xxx у записей с a=1 оказалось null - вернет null.

Comment: @Mike, Не вернет? А как мне прописать-то тогда? Дескать 0 выбранных? У меня код по примеру select xxx from table where a=1.

Comment: я не знаю как оно в джава, но в большинстве языков при работе с базами данных можно узнать сколько _строк_ вернул запрос.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545820/total-number-of-row-resultset-getrow-method

Comment: @Mike, ответом пошлите, я как правильный отмечу. Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и говорил @Mike, все очень ависит от запроса.

Запрос `select xxx from table where a=1` не вернет ни одной строки, если строк с `a=1` не найдет в базе. И следовательно надо проверять количество выбранных строк.

А вот запрос `select max(xxx) from table where a=1` всегда возвращает одну строку и если записей не было, либо поле `xxx` у записей с `a=1` оказалось `null` - вернет `null`.

Чтобы узнать, будет ли вернувшийся ResultSet пустым, нет никакого бесплатного метода (бесплатного по количеству кода или по выполняемым операциям).

Представим, что мы обращаемся к базе так:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:userdata.db");
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select xxx from table where a=1");
```

Рекомендованный способ - сразу начать обрабатывать вернувшиеся rowы, а пустоту или заполненность ResultSet'а отслеживать в булевской переменной по ходу обработки:

```
boolean empty = true;
while( rs.next() ) {
    // Вот здесь нужно обработать ResultSet
    empty = false;
}
if( empty ) {
    // А здесь сделать решение, что делать, если он все-таки пустой
}
```

Есть и другие способы, например, можно написать такой метод:

```
public static boolean isResultSetEmpty(ResultSet resultSet) {
    return !resultSet.first();
}
```

В нем плохо то, что курсор при этом сдвигается на начало. Конечно, если вы и так ничего не делали со своим ResultSet'ом, это совершенно всё равно.

Другой способ - позвать метод `first()` перед совершением какой-либо обработки (фишка в том, что вы должны самостоятельно вручную гарантировать вот это "перед совершением обработки"):

```
if(rs.first()) {
    // ResultSet непустой, делаем что надо
} else {
    // А здесь он пустой
}
```

Но такой метод опять же не инкапсулируешь в функцию красивым способом, он прибит гвоздями к синтаксису Java.

Переусложненный для данной формулировки вопроса, но все же могущий пригодиться в будущем вариант: посчитить общее количество строчек. Ну и если оно больше нуля, то ResultSet, очевидно, не пустой.

```
public static boolean isResultSetEmpty(ResultSet resultSet) {
    return resultSetCountRows(resultSet) == 0;
}
public static int resultSetCountRows(ResultSet resultSet) {
    resultSet.last();
    int rows = resultSet.getRow();
    resultSet.beforeFirst();
    return rows;
}
```